# Evaluate the limit with the Appell F1 function

Tags: limits, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, polygamma

I encountered the limit with the form
$$
\lim_{r\rightarrow 1^+}\frac{1-\frac{1}{r^{d-3}}}{e^{2\kappa r_s(r)}},\quad r_s(r)\equiv r~ F_1\left(-\frac{1}{d-3};-\frac12,1;\frac{d-4}{d-3},-\frac{Q}{r^{d-3}},\frac{1}{r^{d-3}}
\right)
$$
where $r>0$, $F_1$ is the Appell F1 function, $\kappa=\frac12\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+Q}}$, $d=5,6,7,\cdots$ and $Q\geq0$.

**Question:** What is the value of this limit when $Q > 0$?

**What I tried so far:**
When $Q\neq0$, Mathematica gives zero, which is surely wrong as I tested numerically.

I can find the limit in the case of $Q=0$. When $Q=0$, the F1 function reduces to Hypergeometric function
$$
F_1\left(-\frac{1}{d-3};-\frac12,1;\frac{d-4}{d-3},0,\frac{1}{r^{d-3}}
\right)= {}_2F_1\left(
1,\frac{1}{3-d},\frac{1}{3-d}+1,r^{3-d}
\right)
$$
and the limit is given by Mathematica as
$$
\exp\left[{-\gamma_E-\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{3-d}\right)}\right]
$$
where $\gamma_E$ is the Euler gamma and $\psi^{(0)}$ is the polygamma.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! Thank you for the thoughtful question. Could you clarify how you tested this numerically? Also I am confused because you say that the expression is valid for $Q$ including $0$, but want to know the answer when $Q=0$? Or is your question about when $Q \not=0$?

Comment: I gave the explicit values of $Q$ and $d$ and evaluated the limit at some values of $r$ very close to 1. I got convergent results, according to which I said that the answer 0 given by Mathematica is wrong. 
I would like to know the expression of the limit when $Q\neq0$.

Comment: OK I tried to rearrange the question so it is more clear/obvious/easier to find what you're asking. Obviously I don't know the answer myself unfortunately

Comment: Thank you for the improvement!

Comment: The $e^{2k r_s}$ looks like it could be a product of exponentials since the Appel function is essentially a double sum..

Comment: If $\kappa = 1/(2 \sqrt {1 + Q})$, the limit is zero. If $\kappa = (d - 3)/(2 \sqrt {1 + Q})$ and $0 < Q < 1$, my conjecture is that the limit is equal to $e^C$, where
$$C = -\gamma + \frac 1 {2 \sqrt {\pi (1 + Q)}} \sum_{n \geq 0}
 \Gamma {\left( n - \frac 1 2 \right)}
 \psi {\left( n - \frac 1 {d - 3} \right)}
 \frac {(-Q)^n} {n!}.$$